# How to select output of XML Path query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

`Doc` table contains a lot of columns (even not used ones):

```
Doc_DdfID Doc_RentDate Doc_ReturnDate etc.
--------- ------------ -------------- ----
1         2012-07-28   2012-07-28
```

But I want to query just the used ones within `Doc`'s table.

`DocDefinitionFields` list columsn that are in use by document:

```
SELECT Dfl_ColName 
FROM DocDefinitionFields 
WHERE Dfl_DdfID = 1
```

**DocDefinitionFields**:

```
Dfl_ColName
-----------
Doc_RentDate
Doc_ReturnDate
...........
```

So I want to select all columns (listed by second query) from `Doc` table.

**Example** (if 2 columns are added to document definition form I want to select just them):

**Doc**:

```
Doc_RentDate Doc_ReturnDate
------------ --------------
2012-07-28   2012-07-28
```

Tried to do that by subquerying select with concatenation of fields using XML PATH:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT 
       Dfl_ColName + ', ' 
       FROM DocDefinitionFields 
       FOR XML PATH('') 
   ) 
FROM Doc
```

It's not that simple tho. What do you suggest?

Comment: Can you post an example of the result you want?. Also, the version of SQL Server that you are using.

Comment: Posted, using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is dynamic SQL, something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Dfl_ColName FROM DocDefinitionFields FOR XML PATH('') ),1,1,'') + ' FROM Doc'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Also, in order to eliminate additional comma(,) at the end of columns I have added STUFF function along with FOR XML PATH.

Answer (score 1):

To get the column names for a query dynamically and use these in a query you will need to use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-1). Below is an example of how to create the string of available columns

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Columns =  
    COALESCE(@Columns + ', 
     [' + CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR) + ']',
    '[' + CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR) + ']') 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME  
      FROM [SomeDatabase].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'SomeTableName') AS H
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME;
GO
```

You can now use the string of available columns in a Dynamic SQL query. Below we have adopted the above in an `INSERT` query that build the required fields dynamically. The reason why we need to do it in the below is the inclusion of the set field `SomeFieldA` along with the others.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = 
N'INSERT INTO [' + @DbName + N']..[SomeOtherTable] ([SomeFieldA], ' + @Columns + N')  
  SELECT SomeFieldA, ' + @Columns + N' 
  FROM [SomeTableName];';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; 
GO
```

You should be able to amend the above to provide what you need.

I hope this helps.